# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack, how can I make my code more robust?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've had this script running just fine for the past 2 or 3 months, and then for what reason I do not know it just decided it would break on me. I haven't updated Python or any libraries that I am using in this script, but whatever, now I need help fixing it.

To start the dataframe is as follows

```
Company, Registered date, Contact name, Contact email, Contact phone
```

I clean up those columns by converting all to lower case and replacing spaces with '_'

The next step is to split the "contact_name" column which starts out as "(first) (last)" i.e "John Doe" and I want to add 2 columns for first and last. New DF as follows,

```
company, registered_date, contact_name, first_name, last_name, contact_email, contact_phone
```

The program is breaking in the splitting of the contact name and/or creation of the new columns. The line of code I have been using to do this is:

```
df1['first_name'], df1['last_name'] = zip(*df1['registrant_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ', 1)))
```

The traceback says:

```
File "(name).py", line 123
df1['first_name'], df1['last_name'] = zip(*df1['registrant_name'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ', 1)))
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

As I looked through some stuff I found someone with this same issue in using line.split (not inside of Pandas, just python in general) and someone said it's probably because both values aren't there. Sure enough, it seems this is the first time in the 3 months that I somehow ended up with just one value in the "contact_name" column so instead of being "John Doe" it's just "John" (luckily this was literally the first entry in this CSV otherwise I woulda been stumped for a while trying to look through every single row).

So my question is, how do I make my code more robust so that if this issue arises again we can solve it. I'm thinking what I'd like to do is if there is no space it will just take the current value as "first_name" and then add "NaN" as the last name. I just don't know how to do it within a DF since looping is not ideal.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your code you could have avoided the lambda function and used `df1['registrant_name'].str.split()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use *itemgetter* with *str.partition*:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(["foo bar" , "foo", "bar barf"],columns=["name"])
from operator import itemgetter


df['first_name'], df['last_name'] = zip(*df['name'].apply(lambda x: itemgetter(0,2)(x.partition(' '))))
```

That would give you an empty string for missing last names so I am not sure if that is desirable or not.

```
        name first_name last_name
0   foo bar        foo       bar
1       foo        foo          
2  bar barf        bar      barf
```

Not sure if this will be faster or not but it avoids the lambda:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(["foo bar" , "foo", "bar barf"],columns=["name"])
from operator import itemgetter


df['first_name'], df['last_name'] = zip(*map(itemgetter(0, 2), df['name'].str.partition(" ").values))
print(df)
```

Comment: Nice, I had forgotten about `partition`.

Comment: Hmm. is Operator a default library within Python? Or is it something I'd need to install cause it throws a bunch of errors trying to run that code.

Comment: What errors do you get? `operator.itemgetter` is a builtin method

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see the problem. You used 'name' in the df, just had to change that to the actual column name of 'contact_name' :)

Comment: @Mxracer888, yep, I was too lazy to type all those letters ;)

Comment: haha fair enough! It's a good excersice for me to learn how to read through the messages and try to figure at least something out on my own ;) This seems to work beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a way to return `['John', 'Doe']` from `'John Doe'`, and `['John', '']` from `'John'`. This way you will always have two values to unpack.

There are certainly different solutions, but I can suggest one which avoids a loop:

```
x.split(' ', 1) if ' ' in x else [x, '']
```

Plugging this into your `lambda` function should avoid the error you have encountered. Note that it is important to strip white spaces first, as they would make the test invalid:

```
df1['registrant_name'].str.strip().apply(lambda x: x.split(' ', 1) if ' ' in x else [x, ''])
```

Comment: Note that I went a long way to avoid stripping the names twice, as in `x.split() if len(x.split()) > 1 else [x, '']`.